# How do you deploy api made with express in create react app

Tags: express, heroku, create-react-app, react-apollo, apollo-server

I have a simple api created with express.js. When ever i try to push to Heroku it get stuck at this point?

```
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 16.30s.
remote:        
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build (yarn)
remote:        yarn run v1.22.4
remote:        $ node server.js
remote:        Server started on port 9000
```

I also see the same thing in heroku dashboard "View build progress"

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "firebase-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "##########",
  "author": "#######",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --ext js,graphql --ignore data/ server.js",
    "build": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@firebase/app": "^0.6.7",
    "@firebase/component": "^0.1.15",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.15.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-jwt": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase": "^7.15.5",
    "graphql": "^15.3.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "notarealdb": "^0.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

the only thing i have in this project is my server.js. what am i missing or not doing. Basically i trying to deploy this to have a live API for my project. it is working locally but now i would like to have it working live on heroku.

Answer (score 1):

With Heroku, the `build` script is used if you need to [customize your build options](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process) (e.g. if you're using WebPack or TypeScript). The issue is that you're using a script called `build`, which you're expecting to start the application. It's running that script, as it promises to do, but since it's starting the application, it'll "hang forever" from your point of view.

If you change your scripts to this, I think this will solve your issues. Locally, you would use `npm local` for nodemon, and `npm start` would start the app on Heroku.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "local": "nodemon --ext js,graphql --ignore data/ server.js",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
}
```

Comment: thanks Dan Crews and added your changes and it got deployed but now I have 404. I added more notes above.

Comment: @DelormeGrant I recommend you NOT change your original question -- which had a valid answer -- to a new question. StackOverflow exists so that the questions and answers can help the community. Please put your original question back, and if you have a new question, please ask a new question. You're welcome to tag me and I may see it.